# getResult() returns NaN for everything but "Area"

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

I'm trying to get the centroid's `X` and `Y` values from the Results table, but I can't use `getResult()` with anything but `"Area"`. All other columns (which are regularly displayed on the table) return `NaN`.

I'm not using any special plugin, the table is created using `"Analyze Particles..."`

Any idea what could be causing this?

`getResult("Area", 0)` works.

`getResult("X", 0)` does not work. (Returns NaN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured it out. There was a `run("Clear Results...")` line before this loop, and even though it worked well to remove some partial results (scaling), it also bugged the Results columns names for some reason. I replaced it with `IJ.deleteRows(0, 1)`, because there were two measurements regarding the two points used as scale references.